# How random forest classification works behind the scenes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science, random-forest

This is a sample data set of how random forest classification works. I know that building multiple decisions trees by selecting random k points then taking some sort of average?

But here in this case I have 10 trees, with 10 different data points, if I were to select random k points would it look like this:

```
x_train = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
y_train = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
object = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, criterion='entropy')
object.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Then we make a graph and we split the random_k_1 so that it maximizes a category in each split.

Then what do we do? Like take some sort of average? If yes, how are we supposed to do that we only have 0, 1 as y^? I'm sorry for my inability to explain the question I'm just so lost I can't describe the question.

```
random_k_1 = [[10, 0], [30, 1], [70, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, Random Forest works using decision trees. It uses a technique called 'Bootstrapping' or 'Bagging' to reduce the variance in the models.

A number of decision trees are taken (in the sklearn implementation, defined by `n_estimators`). Each of these trees gets to train on a random subsample of the data. This tries to make each tree as independent of the others as possible. Once these are trained, an aggregating technique is used.

To quote from the documentation:

> The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as
> the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The
> class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the
> same class in a leaf.

The predictions are then simply the class with the highest average class probability.

This aggregation is what brings down variance in the model and therefore we go towards the sweet spot of low variance low bias.

I believe your confusion **lies here**. The aggregation in not done for the target label y. The aggregation is done for the **outputs of the various decision trees**.

In an attempt to simplify, consider this example.

You take 11 estimators, i.e 11 Decision Trees in your RandomForest model. y can be [0, 1] integers only.
6 of these decision trees predict y to be 1, where as 5 predict it to be 0. In this case, you choose the prediction of your whole forest to be 1.